# php file_get_contents($url) return strange string

Tags: php

I try to get news from website

> http://www.science-support.ru/news.html

, but I can't extract anything from web page content.
When I apply `file_get_contents()` I get string for which other function don't work. Initially, I try to use `file_get_html()` from `simple_html_dom.php`, but then other functions from this source don't recognize any elements in obtained DOM.

About other function:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.science-support.ru/news.html'); //normal page
$content = substr($content,20); //strange characters
$content_arr = explode( 'div id="box3"' , $content ); //doesn't work

echo $content;
echo $content_arr[0];
?>
```

After substr() I get something like

```
" <�/tr> <�/table> <�/div> <�div id="box3"><�!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="page-content" --> <�h4 class="yellow">14.11.2014 />2>AB8 $>=40/<�/h4> <�p>1JO2;O=K @57C;LB0BK :>=:C@A0 =0 ?@8AC645=85 ?>8A:>2KE 3@0=B>2 ?> @>3@0<<5 =0CG=>-B5E=8G5A:>9 <>45@=870F88 8 ?>2KH5=8N :20;8D8:0F88 <>;>4KE CG5=KE >AA88 2014-2015 33.<�a href="news/news2014-nota-res.html" class="txt" >?>4@>1=55<�/a><�/p>"
```

How can I extract readable content? Thanks

Comment: `other function don't work` what function? What about it doesn't work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Perhaps it breaks on the first characters https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/mPd7o?

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this from Curl i have post some code that will help you

```
<?php

  if( isset( $_POST['site_url'] ) && !empty( $_POST['site_url'] ) ){
    echo get_html($_POST['site_url']);
  } else {
echo 'false';
  }

  function get_html($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
   }

  ?>
```

get website url from your html form this is html how to set

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            <form role="form" id="siteform" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="url" class="form-control" name="site_url" id="site_url" placeholder="Enter your site address">
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
                <button data-loading-text="Please wait..." type="submit" id="url_getter" class="btn btn-default btn-success">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I also get strange characters like "<�h4 class="yellow">02.05.2014 />2>AB8 $>=40/<�/h4> <�p>1JO2;O= :>=:C@A =0 ?@8AC645=85 ?>8A:>2KE 3@0=B>2 ?> @>3@0<<5 =0CG=>-B5E=8G5A:>9 <>45@=870F88 8 ?>2KH5=8N :20;8D8:0F88 <>;>4KE CG5=KE >AA88 2014-2015 33.<�a href="news/news2014-nota.html" class="txt" >?>4@>1=55<�/a><�/p>"

Comment: Problem was solved by application of iconv() in cycle with array of character encodings. I got a readable text if the input charset was UCS-2LE, UTF-16 or UTF-16LE.
`$dir = 'http://www.science-support.ru/news.html';
$dir = file_get_contents($dir);
$encode = mb_list_encodings();
$a = 0;
while ($encode[$a] != null) {
 echo $encode[$a].'>><br>';
 echo iconv($encode[$a], 'utf-8', $dir);
 $a++;
}`